# TypeScript: defining the `in` operator as a function

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that behaves exactly like the `in` operator, where the types are narrowed using [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

(For an example, see [Lodash's `has` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has).)

> For a n in x expression, where n is a string literal or string literal type and x is a union type, the “true” branch narrows to types which have an optional or required property n, and the “false” branch narrows to types which have an optional or missing property n.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator

I have written some tests, showcasing the behaviour of the `in` operator alongside the intended behaviour of our `has` function. How can I define a function (`has`) so that it behaves exactly like the `in` operator in these tests?

```
declare const any: any;

type Record = { foo: string; fooOptional?: string };
type Union = { foo: string; fooOptional?: string } | { bar: number; barOptional?: string };

{
  const record: Record = any;

  if ('foo' in record) {
    record; // $ExpectType Record
  } else {
    record; // $ExpectType never
  }

  if (has(record, 'foo')) {
    record; // $ExpectType Record
  } else {
    record; // $ExpectType never
  }
}

{
  const union: Union = any;

  if ('foo' in union) {
    union; // $ExpectType { foo: string; fooOptional?: string | undefined; }
  } else {
    union; // $ExpectType { bar: number; barOptional?: string | undefined; }
  }

  if (has(union, 'foo')) {
    union; // $ExpectType { foo: string; fooOptional?: string | undefined; }
  } else {
    union; // $ExpectType { bar: number; barOptional?: string | undefined; }
  }
}

{
  const unionWithOptional: { foo: string } | { bar?: number } = any;

  if ('bar' in unionWithOptional) {
    unionWithOptional; // $ExpectType { bar?: number | undefined; }
  } else {
    unionWithOptional; // $ExpectType { foo: string; } | { bar?: number | undefined; }
  }

  if (has(unionWithOptional, 'bar')) {
    unionWithOptional; // $ExpectType { bar?: number | undefined; }
  } else {
    unionWithOptional; // $ExpectType { foo: string; } | { bar?: number | undefined; }
  }
}
```

The closest I've come to solving this is [with this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-414499396):

```
type Discriminate<U, K extends PropertyKey> = U extends any
  ? K extends keyof U
    ? U
    : U & Record<K, unknown>
  : never;

export const has = <T extends object, K extends PropertyKey>(
  source: T,
  property: K,
): source is Discriminate<T, K> =>
  property in source;
```

Unfortunately however the last test does not pass.

For context, the reason I want to do this is so that my custom `has` function can validate the keys at compile time (something which the `in` operator does not do). I can figure that part out—the part I'm struggling with is just mimicking the narrowing performed by `in`.

Answer (score 2):

Without one-sided or fine-grained type guards (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048)) supporting independent behavior for both the true and false side of the guard, it isn't currently possible.

---

What you're asking for is to take a union type `{ foo: string } | { bar?: number }` and come up with a user-defined type guard where the true branch narrows it to `{ bar?: number }` and the false branch leaves it as the full union `{ foo: string } | { bar?: number }`.

Reading through the `getNarrowedType()` function in lines 19788 to 19809 of [`checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/src/compiler/checker.ts), the compiler's type checker, I think that can't happen.

Right now, with a user-defined type guard of type `(x: any) => x is G` applied to a value of *union* type `T`, the compiler will currently *partition* the union type for the true branch and the false branch of the type guard.  So in the true branch you'll get something like `Extract<T, G>` and in the false branch you'll get something like `Exclude<T, G>`.  If a union member is present in the true branch it will be absent in the false branch, and vice versa.

Only if `T` is *not* a union type is it possible for the true branch and false branch narrowings not to be mutually exclusive (and sometimes you'll get `T & G` for the true branch and just `T` for the false branch).

This is not perfect (as per [ms/TS#31156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31156)), but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `has` function can be written in a way which narrows the type of its argument, at least in the case where a key is optional and can be narrowed as non-optional:

```js
function has<T,K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K):
    obj is T & Record<K, Exclude<T[K], undefined>>
{
    return obj[key] !== undefined;
}

type Example = { a: number, b?: number };
let obj: Example = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// inferred obj.b : number|undefined

if(has(obj, 'b')) {
    // inferred obj.b : number
}
```

However, what you're asking for with the `Union` type isn't sound. Consider this example:

```js
type UnsoundUnion = { a: number, b: number } | { c: number, d: number };

let u: UnsoundUnion = { a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 };

if(has(u, 'a')) {
    // it would be wrong to infer u.b : number
}
```

Comment: "it would be wrong to infer u.b : number" – but that's what the `in` operator does. I'm only interested in mimicking the behaviour of the `in` operator.

Comment: In your example, the `in` operator doesn't just infer a type for the `foo` property you tested with `in` - you wanted it to also infer `fooOptional` to be `string | undefined`. That inference is unsound in general, because the existence of the `foo` property doesn't mean that the object's type is from that branch of the union.

Comment: I understand it may be unsound, but that's not really applicable to my question? I want `has` to behave exactly like the `in` operator does in TypeScript (even if that may be unsound)—as demonstrated by my tests, which showcase both methods (both have the same expectations).

Comment: I suspect it isn't possible, because it would require another language construct to be broken in the same way that `in` seems to be. I would also recommend writing your code in a way that depends on an unsound type inference, because if this is fixed in a later version, your code won't type-check any more. Is it possible to do what you want using a tagged union instead?

Comment: The version of `has` I included in my initial question seems to achieve this—that is, it works for the union test cases (matching the behaviour of `in` operator)—so I think it might be possible. It just doesn't pass the final expectation for some reason.

Comment: IIUC, this "unsoundness" comes from the fact that TypeScript allows excess properties in unions without discriminant properties: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863. That may change in the future, but that won't change the behaviour of the `in` operator.